# how to sum value in php with loop

Tags: php, arrays, sum

I'm still learning  `.php`, and I need to sum $FINAL_SCORE. The $FINAL_SCORE is a  variable which stores added value of a field fetched from Database. Here is my example:

```html
<?php $group="1";
   $no=1; $mapel=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM mapel where class_id='$class_id' and group='$group' and id_tp='$id_tp'");while($ux = mysql_fetch_array($mapel)){
  $id_mapel=$ux['id_mapel'];
  
 
$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM student_scores,student_data,score_judul where student_scores.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores.nis=student_data.nis and student_scores.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by student_data.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $amount_TASK=$jm;
if($jm==0){$amount="1";} else {$amount=$jm; };
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n3_100) as rn3_100 FROM student_scores,score_judul where student_scores.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($resut=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn3_100=substr($resut['rn3_100']/$amount,0,5); $AVRG_TASK=$rn3_100;}

$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM student_scores2,student_data,score_judul where student_scores2.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores2.nis=student_data.nis and student_scores2.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and student_scores2.jenis=2 and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by student_data.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $amount_uh=$jm;
if($jm==0){$amount="1";} else {$amount=$jm;};
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n_100) as rn_100 FROM student_scores2,score_judul where student_scores2.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores2.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and student_scores2.jenis=2 and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($resut=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn_100=substr($resut['rn_100']/$amount,0,5); $AVRG_UH= $rn_100;}

$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM student_scores2,student_data,score_judul where student_scores2.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores2.nis=student_data.nis and student_scores2.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and student_scores2.jenis=3 and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by student_data.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $amount_uts=$jm;
if($jm==0){$amount="1";} else {$amount=$jm;};
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n_100) as rn_100 FROM student_scores2,score_judul where student_scores2.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores2.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and student_scores2.jenis=3 and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($resut=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn_100=substr($resut['rn_100']/$amount,0,5); $AVRG_UTS= $rn_100;}

$dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM student_scores2,student_data,score_judul where student_scores2.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores2.nis=student_data.nis and student_scores2.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and student_scores2.jenis=4 and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp' order by student_data.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); $amount_us=$jm;
if($jm==0){$amount="1";} else {$amount=$jm;};
$queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n_100) as rn_100 FROM student_scores2,score_judul where student_scores2.id_score_judul=score_judul.id_score_judul and student_scores2.nis=$nis and score_judul.id_subject=$id_subject and student_scores2.jenis=4 and score_judul.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_judul.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($resut=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn_100=substr($resut['rn_100']/$amount,0,5); $AVRG_US= $rn_100;}

if(!isset($AVRG_TASK)){$AVRG_TASK2=0;}else{$AVRG_TASK2=$AVRG_TASK;};
     if(!isset($AVRG_UH)){$AVRG_UH2=0;}else{$AVRG_UH2=$AVRG_UH;};
     if(!isset($AVRG_UTS)){$AVRG_UTS2=0;}else{$AVRG_UTS2=$AVRG_UTS;};
     if(!isset($AVRG_US)){$AVRG_US2=0;}else{$AVRG_US2=$AVRG_US;};
$amountc=($percent['TASK']*$AVRG_TASK2)/100+($percent['uh']*$AVRG_UH2)/100+($percent['uts']*$AVRG_UTS2)/100+($percent['us']*$AVRG_US2)/100;

       if($amount_TASK!=0){$k=1;} else {$k=0;};
       if($amount_uh!=0){$l=1;} else {$l=0;};
       if($amount_uts!=0){$m=1;} else {$m=0;};
       if($amount_us!=0){$n=1;} else {$n=0;};
       $amount_percent1=($percent['TASK']*$k)+($percent['uh']*$l)+($percent['uts']*$m)+($percent['us']*$n);
       if($amount_percent1==0){$amount_percent=1;}else{$amount_percent=$amount_percent1;};
       $FINAL_SCORE=substr(($amountc/$amount_percent)*100,0,5);

  $dren = mysql_query("SELECT*FROM student_scores,student_data,score_tittle where student_scores.id_score_tittle=score_tittle.id_score_tittle and student_scores.nis=student_data.nis and student_scores.nis=$nis and score_tittle.id_subject=$id_subject and score_tittle.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_tittle.id_tp='$id_tp' order by student_data.id_siswa asc"); $jm=mysql_num_rows($dren); if($jm==0){$amount="1";} else {$amount=$jm;};
  $queryj=mysql_query("SELECT sum(n3_100) as rn3_100, sum(n4_100) as rn4_100, sum(n3_4) as rn3_4, sum(n4_4) as rn4_4 FROM student_scores,score_tittle where student_scores.id_score_tittle=score_tittle.id_score_tittle and student_scores.nis=$nis and score_tittle.id_subject=$id_subject and score_tittle.id_semester='$id_semester' and score_tittle.id_tp='$id_tp'");
while($resut=mysql_fetch_array($queryj))
{$rn3_100=substr($resut['rn3_100']/$amount,0,5); $rn4_100=substr($resut['rn4_100']/$amount,0,5); $rn3_4=substr($resut['rn3_4']/$amount,0,4); $rn4_4=substr($resut['rn4_4']/$amount,0,4);}
?>
                  <?php $name_subject=$ux['name_subject'];
      $an = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT*FROM subject where class_id='$class_id' and name_subject='$name_subject'"));      
      ?>
     
     <text><?php $arr = array ($FINAL_SCORE); echo "" . array_sum($arr) . "\n"; ?></text>
```

So when I put this:
`<?php $arr = array ($FINAL_SCORE); echo "" . array_sum($arr) . "\n"; ?>`
OR this :
`<?php echo $FINAL_SCORE;?>`

The output from both code are:

> 90 90 80

actually I wanna something like `260`, total sum from array... Pls Help..!

Comment: First i want to comment that you are using the outdated mysql_* functions. If you do not want to use PDO or objects, at least use mysqli_*.

Comment: This is horrible to read, please indent your code

Comment: Second I want to point out that you are building your SQL in a dangerous way, which opens you up for SQL Injections. Please escape your inputs, but preferably use PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: $NILAI_AKHIR = $NILAI_AKHIR + substr(($jumlahc/$JUMLAH_PERSEN)*100,0,5);

Comment: Also, if you want to increase the number of developers who can understand and maintain your code, try to use english for class names, class members, functions, and variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 

// here you are inserting only one value into the array
$arr = array ($NILAI_AKHIR); 

// here you are summing up the array which holds only one element
echo "" . array_sum($arr) . "\n"; 
?> 


// the summing done above will naturally then be exactly the same output as this
<?php echo $NILAI_AKHIR;?>
```

If the code above is contained inside a loop, then you need to declare the `$arr` outside that loop, and then add $NILAI_AKHIR each time. Pseudo code below:

```
$arr = [];
while(whatever) //outer loop containing big code above
{
    /**
    *
    * VERY BIG CODE ABOVE GOES HERE
    *
    **/

    $arr[] = $NILAI_AKHIR;
}

// finished very big loop
$sum = 0;
$output = "";
while($element = array_shift($arr)){
    $sum += $element;
    $output .= $element;
    if(sizeof($arr) > 0){
        $output .= " + ";
    }
}

echo $output . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Hi Buddy, there is a problem when I tried to `count (arr)` , the result  = `0`.. it supposed to be `3` not `0`.  Any Idea..?

Comment: @Azva did you forget the '$'?

Comment: Ok, so when I tried `count($arr)` or `sizeof($arr)`, the result = `1`. not `3`.. any suggestion..?!

Comment: @Azva make sure you are outside the loop as in my answer above

Comment: Hi Again, this my last question. is it possible to rank `$sum`...?! So the highest number = `1`  etc,, and so on.. Can u help me out..

Comment: @Azva If your are talking about ordering the array with the highest sum first, then you can simply sort it using `asort()`

Comment: Pls check this out...[rank in php based on average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616128/rank-in-php-based-on-average-values).. Need more suggetion.. ty

Comment: @Azva as both I have stated earlier, and others in that post points out, your arrays only contains one element. Remember in THIS question, you had to move the declaration outside the BIG CODE LOOP, put each avg into the array inside the loop, then after the loop, sort the array using asort ans the rank is the same as the array index plus one.